# How do I specify a DateFormat to use for all Restsharp requests on a given client?

Tags: windows-phone-7, iso8601, restsharp

My rest service uses ISO 8601 as the date format for all requests and responses. Is there a way to set this on the `RestClient` or do I need to set it on each individual `RestRequest`?

Comment: I was going to say to inherit from RestRequest and override the DateFormat but its not marked virtual.

Comment: I ended up just using a factory method to create my `RestRequest`s. Not the best solution but slightly easier than overriding the serializer in my opinion.

Comment: @BryanAnderson: Are you using XML or JSON for your output format? The DateFormat property appears to only be used on the XML side of RestSharp's serializer.

Comment: I'm using JSON. Setting the DateFormat on the RestRequest in a factory method seems to work okay. return new RestRequest(resource, method) { DateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss.FFF", RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

Comment: Hi Brian - I can confirm that DateFormat does not affect the format of a JSON request. I'm looking at the code that sets DateFormat as you specify, but in Fiddler I can see the date gets sent as something like "/Date(1339005511262-0500)/"

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like there's any built in ability to do so. Newtonsoft.Json provides an IsoDateTimeConverter that can do the serialization you are looking for. In order to use it for serialization, I think you would need to mostly duplicate the RestSharp.Serializers.JsonSerializer in your own ISerializer that does almost exactly what the RestSharp version does, but tweaksthe NewtonSoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Converters property in the instance created [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs#L44) and adds/replaces the date/time converter.

As far as deserialization, you should be able to set the IDeserializer.DateFormat property on a new JsonDeserializer and setting that as your handler:

```
client.AddHandler ("application/json", new JsonDeserializer() { DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz" });
```

Comment: It seems easier to just set the `RestRequest.DateFormat` property. I was just hoping there was a way to set it on the `RestClient` so I wouldn't have to put it on each individual `RestRequest`.

Comment: @BryanAnderson you could use a helper method/factory to create the `RestRequest`

Comment: @drzaus That's what I ended up doing iirc

Comment: RestRequest.DateFormat' is obsolete: 'Add custom content handler instead. This property will be removed